# Block Mac UI controls painting/redrawing

Tags: macos, cocoa, controls, paint

Hello I was wondering if anyone could shed some light how I may enable/disable redrawing of any class inherited from a nsview?

I know Windows has a message you can send to a hwnd to enable/disable gadget painting messages. This also then propagates to child hwnds too. Is there an equivalent method in Mac development?

I have an existing GUI library and I was wondering if there is a method to do this that doesn't require modification of the existing source code?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why is it a problem if the controls repaint?

Comment: just for the record: The trouble is the library I am using potentially was causing many individual paints as it was setting up a ton of small gadgets/views. I was looking for a way to augment the library (without altering the libraries source) to enable a block on repainting the views until I am ready.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem is that you're doing a lot of control layout work and don't want drawing to occur while this is happening, you can use either `[NSWindow disableScreenUpdatesUntilFlush]` or the global `NSDisableScreenUpdates()` and `NSEnableScreenUpdates()` functions to prevent the screen updating until you're ready.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure exactly what you are trying to do, but imagine you have an NSView subclass that has a draw method

.h

```
BOOL shouldDraw;
```

.m

```
-(void)drawRect:(NSRect)someRect
{
    if(shouldDraw)
    {
        [super drawRect:someRect];
    }
}
```

if you never call super's implementation of draw, nothing will get drawn.

Comment: Assuming it's not a layer-hosting view. (In a layer-hosting view, drawing/image-holding is done by the layer(s), not the view; the view never receives `drawRect:` and any measures taken there to prevent drawing will have no opportunity to have an effect.)

Comment: I am tryin to effect any existing control. Eg a textfield, button, etc .. Are you saying I would have to subclass each? My aim is to prevent the GUI library I am using from sending too many reprints by temporarily disabling painting of a control...

Comment: you may be prematurely optimizing, on the mac basically views won't draw every time there is a change, they will just draw periodically if they need to. you can do some profiling to test, but I suspect you probably aren't going to get the gains that you expect.

Comment: you can also do something like [aView setNeedsDisplay:NO]...draw draw draw... wait wait wait... [aView setNeedsDisplay:YES]; which would be more aqua like.

Comment: @Skn3: That's handled for you by the operating system, which tells views when to draw and already tries to minimize drawing attempts (via coalescing and the 60 Hz timer). Are you witnessing a performance problem that you've proven in Instruments is caused by excessive drawing? If so, is it not possible to change your usage of the library, or the library itself, to resolve the problem?

Comment: @GradyPlayer: Huh? `setNeedsDisplay:` affects whether the view will be sent `drawRect:` on the next drawing cycle; why would you set it to `NO`, then do some manual drawing, then set it to `YES` after you've drawn?

Comment: It is mainly for a gadget built of many smaller gadgets. I'd like to disable on the parent view add many sub views and then enable on the parent causing the entire region to be validated at once. Does the mac even do it this way? Interesting that it already sets redraws periodically...

Comment: @Skn3: The parent view doesn't draw the subviews; the subviews draw themselves. That will happen after you get back to the event loop, so if you're adding a bunch of views in response to a single event, they will all draw at once anyway.

Comment: But the parent views clip the sub views surely? Besides it is more redrawing only once the sub view has been fully configured. Eg create button, resize button, set button icon, redraw button. Imagine if there was a redraw after each step, it would be a waste. Each action in the lib is considered seperate so to my original question I am lookin for a solution that can override the flaw in the library

Comment: @Skn3: There isn't a redraw after each of those steps if you aren't waiting for an event before each one.

Comment: @peter hosey, I guess what I meant was that if they were using some sort of a buffer, an image or just a chunk of memory, if they said setNeedsDisplay:NO at the beginning of filling the buffer, then setNeedsDisplay at the end, they wouldn't blit until after the buffer was full, but that doesn't sound like what they are doing anyway.

Comment: ah ok well thats good to know there is no redraw there! I think my original concept of this question is now altered but @RobKeniger 's answer does infact answer the original question. Thanks for the assistance. I hope I'm right in awarding the answer to Rob?